# Prepared Statement with inner join, on multiple databases at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, database, prepared-statement, inner-join

I am sure this has been answered, if so I would like to know where.

Databases 
I have two Databases "Conn" and "Conn2"

```
Conn host a table called Account.
Account has 2 columns: User_Key,Username
```

```
Conn2 has a table called Miles 
Miles has 3 Columns: Miles_Key,Miles_User_Key, Miles_Amount
```

What I would like to do is create a leader board.

I would like to Pull the Miles_Amount from Conn2 and use a SUM function to get a total value. While using INNER JOIN ON Miles_User_Key = User_Key to get the Username from Conn.

I can do this all fine and dandy with a single database, but I have no clue on how to do this with a dual databases.

```
$LB_User_Query = "  SELECT Miles_User_Key, Username, SUM(Miles_Amount) AS 'Miles' 
                    FROM Miles 
                    INNER JOIN Account
                         ON Account_Stats.Account_Stats_Account_Key = Miles.Miles_User 
                    GROUP BY Miles.Miles_User 
                    ORDER BY Miles Desc";
$LB_User_stmt = $Conn->prepare($LB_User_Query);
$LB_User_stmt->execute();                           
$LB_User_stmt->bind_result($Miles_User_Key, $Username, $Miles);
```

On a side note, if you are wondering why the account, and the miles are in two separate databases it is because we have two separate sites with the same accounts populating each..

Comment: I believe you need a federated database engine to do what you are asking.

Comment: you can't join across different connections. no way, no how.

Answer (score 0):

To pull data from seperate databases, just prepend the table name with the database name. So instead of using `Account`, you would use `Conn.Account`, and instead of `Miles`, you would just use `Conn2.Miles`.

Comment: oh, awesome. I will try that out.. I was thinking it was something similar I just needed clarification. So I would assume something like database.table.column?

Comment: What about the prepare section of the query, does anything need to be changed there?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since it is apparently impossible to link two separate database connections to one single query. I setup a table on the $conn connection to push the user's name into, so I could pull it out when I run this query with only one database connection.